# Unity (compiz) doesn't work with Xinerama and AMD GPUs

Tags: unity, ati, compiz, xinerama

Using 2 AMD gpus to power 3 monitors, when I enable Xinerama and reboot Unity doesn't open.

I am using the 12.11 beta drivers from ATI and 12.10 version of Ubuntu.

Here is a log using the Unity --reset command.

http://pastie.org/pastes/5565331/text

The log mentions several files it can't find and ends with:

```
compiz (core) - Fatal: No composite extension
```

I've tried using KDE and Gnome Classic and Xinerama is working well there. However using Compwiz --reset in those Window Manager results in the same compiz (core) - Fatal: No composite extension error. So that can't be why Xinerama isn't working, right?

Any help here would be appreciated. Multi monitor support is crucial :(

Comment: Xinerama will never work with Composite. Unfortuantly, you are out of luck until XRandR supports multi-GPU.